# UIViewController with customized screen frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, avfoundation

I am trying to present a `UIViewController` that only takes up part of the screen.

On iPad, I know this is possible by specifying a type of transition, but I want to do this on iPhone so that the controller can be created to take up a certain `CGRect` on top of the current view controller being displayed. Ideally, I want to be able to do this by specifying a `CGRect` in the constructor for the view controller, like so:

```
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame;
```

Before would look like so:

[image]

And after would look something like so:

[image]

I know this might not sound like an ideal use case, but the purpose is to specify a live camera preview in a specific frame. I know I *can* get this by just specifying a view as a subview of what I'm currently on, but I am trying to provide a full fledged camera API that can have it's preview size customized.

Comment: you should read up on childViewControllers. will work perfectly for your case

Comment: You should be able to create a custom UIView sized how you want it and then you can set the previewLayer.frame from the camera to the UIview.frame and it would then be scaled appropriately